# How to align image with hr line with another image html CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is what I want:

```
IMAGE1 ------------- IMAGE2
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
IMAGE3 ------------- IMAGE4
```

I couldn't make that perfect alignment. I am using `<hr tag>` for
the alignment. Please can someone help me.

Here's my code :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>IP address</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><hr size = "10" color = "green" width = 20% align = "left">
<a href = "index.php"><img src = "images\router.png" width = "100" height = "100" alt = "Router">Router 1</img></a></hr></p>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<a href = "index.php"><img src = "images\router.png" width = "100" height = "100" alt = "Router">Router 2</img></a>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<a href = "index.php"><img src = "images\router.png" width = "100" height = "100" alt = "Router">Router 3</img></a>


&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


<a href = "index.php"><img src = "images\router.png" width = "100" height = "100" alt = "Router">Router 4</img></a><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Help me please

Comment: What code have you already tried already? What are you currently struggling with? SO is not a "I need this; give me code" service. You need to provide something to reproduce the issue you're having. Code => answers

Comment: I'm so sorry. This is my code
<p><hr size = "10" color = "green" width = 20% align = "left">
<a href = "index.php"><img src = "images\router.png" width = "100" height = "100" alt = "Router">Router 1</img></a></hr></p>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<a href = "index.php"><img src = "images\router.png" width = "100" height = "100" alt = "Router">Router 2</img></a>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

Comment: What is your code?..

Comment: @GeoffJames There is my code sir so far

Comment: Then, wouldn't it be a great idea to put that in your OP?

Comment: @GeoffJames OP? what is that sir . Sorry i'm just a newbie here

Comment: Edit your original question, and include your code in it :)

Comment: @GeoffJames done sir

Comment: @GeoffJames Sir where are you

Comment: I'm sat on the sofa, drinking coffee

Comment: @GeoffJames i've already given the code above

Comment: This is vertical align for 3 elements. You tried to use the responses for the similar questions or the documentation? http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/299/centering/10360/vertically-align-an-image-inside-div#t=201608151151569658618

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a container box and add 4 divs with images in it. With position absolute you can control the position.

HTML

```
<div class="image-box">
  <div class="image image-top-left">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/2"/>
  </div>
  <div class="image image-top-right">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/1"/>
  </div>
  <div class="image image-bottom-left">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/2"/>
  </div>
  <div class="image image-bottom-right">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/2"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image-box {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px dotted green;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
}

.image-top-left {
  top: -25px;
  left: -25px;
}

.image-top-right {
  top: -25px;
  right: -25px;
}

.image-bottom-left {
  bottom: -25px;
  left: -25px;
}

.image-bottom-right {
  bottom: -25px;
  right: -25px;
}
```

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/frankspin/pen/ZOwmaG)

Comment: Sir the border the doesn't work with me . i want an <hr tag> but it always overlap with the image